# How to bootstrap Guice and make it available to non Jersey JAX-RS resources?

Tags: java, jax-rs, guice, bootstrapping

- Using `GuiceServletContextListener` is not an option, as the API requests are not handled by servlets.
- Jersey's `GuiceContainer` cannot be leveraged as the application uses non-Jerset JAX-RS implementation (using WebSphere).

As there is no single entry point, no main method from which, `guice.createInjector(MODULES)` could be called, what options am I left with?

Is it a good design to provider a static `Injector` which loads the modules once during application bootup and in the JAX-RS resource, access my interface using `injector.getInstance(MyInterface.class)`?